# How can I remove 'months' from the column and divide the leftover values by 12?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the pandas dataframe I'm working with, values in column A look like

```
**A**
6 months
3
1
6 months
4
1
6 months
```

Now I need to standardize this so that it looks like. data type of column A is 'object'

```
**A**
0.5
3
1
0.5
4
1
0.5
```

So I need to remove 'months' and divide the remaining digit in that cell by 12 so that the whole column is standardized in YEARS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether your column A does not contain 'months' using `~..str.contains()` and do nothing on it, otherwise, remove the 'months' text, convert to `int` and divide by 12 `div(12)`:

```
import numpy as np
df['**A**'] = np.where(~df['**A**'].str.contains('months',na=False),df['**A**'],
                       df['**A**'].replace(r'months','',regex=True).astype(int).div(12))
```

---

```
Out[134]: 

  **A**
0   0.5
1     3
2     1
3   0.5
4     4
5     1
6   0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) method:-

```
df['A']=df['A'].apply(lambda x:x if x.isnumeric() else int(x.split(' ')[0])/12)
```

Comment: if this helped you then try considering accept this answer...thanks :)